# How to set image as wallpaper with jetpack compose

Tags: android, image, android-jetpack-compose

How can we set a image as device wallpaper with jetpack compose. I'm dont know how we can get get drawable from Image composeable with jetpack compose [My ui screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovd8z.png)

I have tried some approaches but not works.

Comment: Where did you get the drawable you are showing in the image from?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No I'm just loading an image from url via rest api. I just want to extract bitmap for that image which is showing in Image Composable. Like we can get bitmap from ImageView in xml approach.

Comment: Basically I just want to set that image as wallpaper on device which I am loading from url in Image Composable.